# Internet Explorer shows UL without right styling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sass, internet-explorer-11

Basically I've got 3 `ul` inside one `div`. All of em are floated beneath and every browser shows it correct except Internet Explorer. I tested it with IE 11
[image: Internet Explorer 11]

Jsfiddle (html/scss): https://jsfiddle.net/gs7wmgf7/

It should look like this

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: For that matter, the externally linked live demo doesn't even work in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Although the demo doesn't work, I can see you are using `flex-basis`. There is a known bug with this property in Internet Explorer where it behaves incorrectly if there is no unit.

Try changing `flex-basis: 0` to `flex-basis: 0%`.